# Get correct coordinates of feature when projection is wrapped around dateline / OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

When I use a wrapped world projection the retrival of feature coordinates doesn't get the right "repitition" of the world, if it's not the center one. In detail:

In OpenLayers 3 I have a vectormap which is wrapped around the dateline:

```
new ol.source.Vector({ ... wrapX: true});
```

When I fetch the features at an event pixel via

```
var feature = map.world.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
  return feature;
});
```

The coordinates I get via

```
var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
```

... are always the same no matter in which "repetition" of the wrapped world I hover. Then I position an `ol.Overlay` via

```
overlay.setPosition(coords);
```

And this positioning also doesn't detect the repitition, which leads to the behaviour, that the overlay is positioned off the view, when the "central world" is panned of the screen.

EDIT: Actually the problem can be seen in this OL3 example:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/icon.html?q=overlay ... just zoom out until the icon appears again to the left or right and click on it. The popover will appear in the central version.

Comment: Is it possible to fork an OL3 [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/pa9prLge/) to show us the problem?

Comment: @DennisBauszus there is actually an OL3 example, that illustrates the problem. See edit.

Comment: I found a workaround that works for the moment. I'll post it as an answer, later.

Comment: You could try the internal coordinates, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30803366/4640499).

Comment: Internal coordinates won't help since the clicked feature is always bound to the -180-180 coordinate space, even if it is displayed outside that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you have found a workaround, but here's a solution that will work for you.

Basically, you want to your offset to the 'central world', or the -180 to 180 range by normalizing:

```
// Inside map.on('click', function (evt) {

/** Find Offset **/
var clickedon = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(evt.pixel)
var offset = Math.floor((clickedon[0] / 40075016.68) + 0.5);

// Popup handling.
```

Then you want to apply the offset to the coordinates where you're showing the popup:

```
/** Add offset **/
coord[0] += (offset * 20037508.34 * 2);
```

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ttc8603/) for full working code.

Comment: Great! That's what I did in my "workaround" ... just needed some more lines for the offset computation :-). Still feels a bit like workaround, but it works well. And actually I can't say which function I would expect to behave differently.